# MS translator request not authorized

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have this simple code to get translation:

```
    var apiurl = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0';
    var my_token = 'xxxxxx'; // my sekret key
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: apiurl,
            dataType: "json",
            jsonp: "oncomplete",
            crossDomain: true,
            context: this,
            data: {
                text: 'Test simple text',
                from: 'en',
                to: 'de'
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', my_token);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-ClientTraceId', uuid());
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region', 'westeurope');
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            },
            complete: function (msg) {
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

But I got always error 401000 The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid.

I used secred ID from picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows an app registration configuration page in Azure Active Directory - this is something entirely different. What you want is [creating a Translator resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-how-to-signup#create-your-resource) and then take one of the keys from the "Keys and Endpoints" menu:

[image]

Comment: Crazy how difficult is registration of any service.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Looks good. Now I have: {"error":{"code":400000,"message":"One of the request inputs is not valid."}}

Comment: How do you run this JavaScript code? In a browser or in the backend (e.g. Node.js?). If in a browser, you'll likely run into the problem that the translate API doesn't return proper "Access-Control-*" headers and therefore your browser blocks the request due to CORS.

Answer (score 0):

With the following adjustments, the code should work:

- use in **my_token** one of the subscription keys under "Azure portal > Translator resource > Keys and Endpoint > Key 1 or Key 2"
- check the region for **Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region** (also required for authentication), use the term under "Azure portal > Translator resource > Keys and Endpoint > Region"
- insert in **apiurl**: `&from=en&to=de`
- change **data** in: `JSON.stringify([{ 'text': 'Test simple text' }])`

```js
var apiurl = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=de';
var my_token = 'xxxxxx'; // subscription key
jQuery.ajax({
    url: apiurl,
    dataType: "json",
    jsonp: "oncomplete",
    crossDomain: true,
    context: this,
    data: JSON.stringify([{ 'text': 'Test simple text' }]),
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', my_token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-ClientTraceId', uuid());
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region', 'westeurope');
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    complete: function (msg) {
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

function uuid() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  );
}
```